# listPlugin FullCalendar didn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, angular8

I have this code :

```
....
import { FullCalendarComponent } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import timeGrigPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
....
fullCalendarOptions = {
    allDaySlot: false,
    columnHeader: false,
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    defaultView: 'timeGridDay',
    header: {
        right: '',
        center: '',
        left: 'title'
    },
    height: 'auto',
    locale: this.translateService.currentLang,
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGrigPlugin],
    ....
}
....
```

I have the error : `Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin`. But if I remove from plugin list : `listPlugin` all works just fine.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of `@fullcalendar/list` in your `package.json`. Does it match the versions of the other plugins you have installed?

I was facing this same issue just a couple hours ago, and I found that the versions were mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem. I updated @fullcalendar and all plugins and it solved my problem